# What is the regional use of "genial"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, uso-de-palabras

What parts of the Spanish-speaking world regularly use the word **genial**? Is it only encountered in Spain, or is it common in other regions as well?

It seems like it's more widespread than I realized, despite I've rarely (or never) heard it used during visits to Central America.

Comment: It's quite common here in Mexico. Although I don't know if context/usage varies.

Comment: Is widely used in Argentina as well. But mostly it's a very common word in Latin America-

Comment: Here in Chile it's also used.

Comment: Thinking about it, I know it mostly from the subtitles of English-language movies. I use it as a clue to guess whether the subtitles were done in Mexico or Spain but it may rather be a way they use to sound non-regional.

Comment: @jrdioko: "genial" is just a normal word. But I'm assuming you're actually asking about the one sense that means "cool", "awesome", etc. If so you should include that in your question.

Comment: Don't forget the classic "Awesombroso" a mix with awesome and asombroso.

Comment: It's very commonly used in sarcastic way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Genial" is widely understood in all spanish speaking countries as it is a fairly common word.

But for usage there are many differences in how often it is used. (In common speech, speaking with friends etc...)

Spain, Argentina, Peru and Mexico generally use "genial". (Mexico uses **chido** as well and Spain **molón**)

But some other countries don't use it as often such, as

- Colombia: uses more **chévere** or **chimba** or **bacano** (depending on context)
- Ecuador: uses more **arrecho** (Can have a sexual meaning but is mostly to express genial or cool. ie. Qué arrecho!

This answer is rather incomplete as I can't know every country, but I can attest for those countries.

Comment: The English Wiktionary has assembled a pretty good collection of [translations for English "cool" into lots of varieties of Spanish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cool#Translations).

Answer (score 6):

Genial is used by all the countries that use spanish as a primary language, as it is actually a word with a meaning (i.e not a slang word), you can see its definition [here](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=genial) by the Real Academia Española which is pretty much the most reliable source whenever you have a doubt about a word, it is common in Mexico and other South American countries where I've been.

Comment: RAE's 4th definition for *genial* is "magnífico, estupendo," without any regional or dialectal notes. Sounds like widespread usage, just like Rafael said!

Comment: @rafael: You have a typo: "whebever" should be "whenever".

Comment: It's not a great idea to take everything the RAE says as gospel, especially if you don't have the latest editions. They were not very open to regional Spanish until a few years ago and are still catching up. I have the latest printed RAE plus a small collection of regional Central American dictionaries are there's lots in the latter still missing from the former.

Comment: what would be the best source then @hippietrail ? Anyway my point was that "genial" is used by anyone who speaks Spanish.

Comment: The RAE may be the best single source but they do have a definite weakness when it comes to regionalisms, especially for Latin America. It's a great source but for regional issues it's best to have other sources too. In any case your point is correct about it being a plain old word as well as having a slang sense which might depend on the place so I asked the OP to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite used in Argentina, coloquially, sometimes as an adjective but more as an adverb or isolated interjection (vrey much like 'great' in english).