# ¿Qué colombianismos se pueden escuchar en la película "Encanto" de Disney?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos, colombia

He visto *[Encanto](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2953050/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)* varias veces, y escuchado su banda sonora aún más veces. Agradezco enormemente que Disney haya tomado la decisión de doblar las películas al español usando únicamente la variante hablada en el país donde transcurre la acción (si este es uno de habla hispana), como ha pasado ya con *Coco* y la citada *Encanto*.

Quisiera pues aprovechar la oportunidad para estudiar las palabras y expresiones típicas de Colombia que hacen acto de presencia en la traducción. El problema que tengo es que a veces no sé si lo que estoy oyendo es una licencia de los traductores para encajar mejor la letra de una canción (como sucede con un uso intransitivo del verbo *intentar* en la canción de Bruno). Tampoco creo que hayan tirado mucho de expresiones que solo se entiendan allí, dado que la traducción se iba a usar en todo el mundo. Pero seguro que alguna se ha colado.

Así pues, ¿qué palabras o expresiones usadas típicamente en Colombia se han usado en la versión doblada al español de *Encanto* de Disney?

Answer (score 3):

> <sup><sub>Esta es una respuesta comunitaria, siéntete libre de modificarla a tu antojo para mejorarla y añadir más información.</sub></sup>

---

#### De una

Al principio de la canción sobre la familia Madrigal, Mirabel exclama:

> *—¡De una!*

Esta expresión está recogida [en el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/uno) como sinónima de "de una vez". Sin embargo, [el DAMER aclara](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=una) que tanto en Colombia como en Venezuela, Ecuador y Paraguay se usa con el significado de "al punto, sin dilación".

#### Pa/ma

Tampoco exactamente colombianismos, estas expresiones para designar cariñosamente al padre y la madre son comunes a varios países de hispanoamérica. De hecho, el Damer ni siquiera considera que *[pa](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pa)* sea de uso en Colombia, pero si se usa en la película será por algo. A su vez, *ma* ni siquiera aparece en el Damer, mas la usan también en la película.

> *El tío Félix quiso a Pepa
>
> y mi pa quiso a Julieta.*

#### Bacano

En un momento dado, Mirabel comenta:

> *Es bacano tener un amigo.*

[El DLE registra](https://dle.rae.es/bacano) esta palabra como una versión usada exclusivamente en Colombia de *[bacán](https://dle.rae.es/bac%C3%A1n)*, que significa "muy bueno, estupendo, excelente". Sin embargo, [el DAMER amplía](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=bacano) el uso de esta palabra también a Ecuador y República Dominicana, le da el significado de "chévere, estupendo", y la marca como lenguaje juvenil.

Comment: ¡Buen compendio! De _bacano_ también se habló en [What is the regional use of "genial"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/195/1674)

Answer (score 2):

**Parcerito**

Cuando Mirabel esta hablándole a Antonio debajo de la cama le dice:

[image]

> Ok Parcerito, ¿estas listo?

**Parcerito** es el diminutivo de Parcero, que significa **amigo o compañero**.

https://spanishvip.com/vocabulary/colombian-slang/